# Try to prepopulate room database

Tags: java, android, insert, android-room

I'm trying to build a database that has two tables with a one to many relationship.
(one recipe belongs to many ingredients)

It looks like I have setup everything correctly I think but now when I build the database I want to pre-populate is with some recipes and the ingredients that belong to the recipe. But I don't know how to implement this in the database builder.

Here is my recipe table:

```
@Entity(tableName = "recipe_table") //Represents the table in SQLite database
public class Recipe {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id; //Holds the id of the recipe

    private String title; //Holds the name of the recipe

    @Ignore
    private List<Ingredient> ingredientsList;

    //Generate constructor to create objects later
    public Recipe(String title, List<Ingredient> ingredientsList) {
        this.title = title;
        this.ingredientsList = ingredientsList;
    }

    //Generate getters to persist values to the database
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    //Generate setter so that room can recreate later
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public List<Ingredient> getIngredientsList() {
        return ingredientsList;
    }

    public void setIngredientsList(List<Ingredient> ingredientsList) {
        this.ingredientsList = ingredientsList;
    }
}
```

A Ingredient table:

```
package com.example.kookrecepten;

import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.ForeignKey;
import androidx.room.Ignore;
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;

import java.util.List;

import static androidx.room.ForeignKey.CASCADE;

@Entity(foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = Recipe.class, parentColumns = "id", childColumns = "recipeId", onDelete = CASCADE))
public class Ingredient {
    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;
    private int recipeId;
    private String title; //Name of the ingredient
    @Ignore
    private List<Ingredient> ingredientsList;
    public Ingredient(String title, int recipeId) {
        this.title = title;
        this.recipeId = recipeId;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setRecipeId(int recipeId) {
        this.recipeId = recipeId;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getRecipeId() {
        return recipeId;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

This is my dao file

```
@Dao
public abstract class RecipeDao {
    //Insert recipe
    @Insert
    public abstract void insertRecipe(Recipe recipe);

    //Insert ingredients list
    @Insert
    public abstract void insertIngredientList(List<Ingredient> ingredients);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM recipe_table WHERE id =:id")
    public abstract Recipe getRecipe(int id);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Ingredient WHERE recipeId =:recipeId")
    public abstract List<Ingredient> getIngredientList(int recipeId);

    public void insertRecipeWithIngredients(Recipe recipe) {
        List<Ingredient> ingredients = recipe.getIngredientsList();
        for (int i = 0; i < ingredients.size(); i++) {
            ingredients.get(i).setRecipeId(recipe.getId());
        }
        insertIngredientList(ingredients);
        insertRecipe(recipe);
    }

    public Recipe getRecipeWithIngredients(int id) {
        Recipe recipe = getRecipe(id);
        List<Ingredient> ingredients = getIngredientList(id);
        recipe.setIngredientsList(ingredients);
        return recipe;
    }
}
```

But my problem is I have no idea how to prepopulate my database.

```
private static class PopulateDbAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private RecipeDao recipeDao;

        private PopulateDbAsyncTask(RecipeDatabase db) {
            recipeDao = db.recipeDao();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            recipeDao.insertRecipeWithIngredients(
                    //insert a recipe and a list of ingredients?
            );
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate

Answer (score 1):

**First** of all, I recommend you NOT to you AsyncTask as it's **deprecated**. hit [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) for more details.

**Secondly** you 3 options for prepopulating your database as follow:

1) **createFromAssets**: in this option, you may create a directory called "databases" under assets folder
so your could will be as follow:

```
.createFromAssets("/databases/YOUR DATABASE FILENAME")
```

2) **createFromFile**: This option may work with the file you are assigning its path.

```
.createFromFile(File("YOUR FILE PATH"))
```

if you are stuck with these two solutions, you can try the manual solution, we may call it manual solution yeah !. by accessing your database file in assets folder.

```
    private fun copyDBFromStorage(databaseName: String) {
    if (checkIfDBExists(this, databaseName)) return
    val databaseFile = File(this.getDatabasePath(databaseName).toString())
    val sourceLocation = assets.open("Your database file path")
    try {
        val inputStream = sourceLocation
        val os = FileOutputStream(databaseFile)
        val buffer = ByteArray(1024 * 32)
        var length = inputStream.read(buffer)
        while (length > 0) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, length)
            length = inputStream.read(buffer)
        }
        os.flush()
        os.close()
        inputStream.close()

    } catch (ex: IOException) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw  RuntimeException("Error copying storage database");
    }
}

private fun checkIfDBExists(
    context: Context,
    databaseName: String
): Boolean {
    val dbfile = File(context.getDatabasePath(databaseName).toString())
    if (dbfile.exists()) return true
    if (!dbfile.parentFile.exists()) {
        dbfile.parentFile.mkdirs()
    }
    return false
}
```

I hope this would help

Happy coding